# pip install cssselect Weird Error

Tags: installation, pip

I need help with the following error message below.

Thanks,
Mittervi.

```
Username-MacBook-Pro:~ usernameremoved$ pip install cssselect
Collecting cssselect
  Using cached cssselect-0.9.1.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: cssselect
  Running setup.py install for cssselect
    error: could not create '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/cssselect': Permission denied
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/86/t2qqsky97xzgsl4kvhgsr1jh0000gn/T/pip-build-DP_x6t/cssselect/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/86/t2qqsky97xzgsl4kvhgsr1jh0000gn/T/pip-psclw0-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
running install

running build

running build_py

creating build

creating build/lib

creating build/lib/cssselect

copying cssselect/__init__.py -> build/lib/cssselect

copying cssselect/parser.py -> build/lib/cssselect

copying cssselect/tests.py -> build/lib/cssselect

copying cssselect/xpath.py -> build/lib/cssselect

running install_lib

creating /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/cssselect

error: could not create '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/cssselect': Permission denied

----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/86/t2qqsky97xzgsl4kvhgsr1jh0000gn/T/pip-build-DP_x6t/cssselect/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/86/t2qqsky97xzgsl4kvhgsr1jh0000gn/T/pip-psclw0-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/86/t2qqsky97xzgsl4kvhgsr1jh0000gn/T/pip-build-DP_x6t/cssselect
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it using.

sudo pip install cssselect